# How to scroll all sheets together (or other ~3D-like ideas)

Tags: scroll, 3d, libreoffice-calc

I would like a "3D" spreadsheet, with the aim of having main entries in the normal 2D cells and then (potentially just-as-important) entries in a third dimension above each cell. This is what the multiple sheets already allow for, the problem is that I cannot easily see all the 3rd dimension cells at once.

I was first hoping to find some sophisticated method of using actual 3D sheets but with no luck so far. I realised that if I could only make sure the other sheets would line up with my first sheet then that would be good enough, so I could "scroll" along the third dimension by switching between sheets.

So, is there any way to scroll all the sheets together?

Such that if I scroll down on sheet 1 to see cell 123 A, when I switch to sheet 2, cell 123 A is in the same position on the screen, and so on for sheets 3 and up.

If this is impossible but anyone has suggestions for a different solution (even using a different program (on Linux)) that would be great.

Comment: Not sure the exact implementation, but if you're savvy enough, you could implement the events talked about [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm) (handling the window's events) and force a scroll of the other sheets. I have no idea how cumbersome or process intensive this would be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm definitely not savvy enough, and it looks like that's specific to MS Excel anyway rather than libreoffice or something else I can use on linux?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see he tags, just assumed Excel. Hope you find what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete working solution in OpenOffice Basic:

```vb
Global OldSheet As Object
Global HandlingActivationEvent As Boolean

Sub RegisterMyActivationEventListener
    oListener = CreateUnoListener( _
        "ActivListener_", "com.sun.star.sheet.XActivationEventListener" )
    oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController
    oController.addActivationEventListener(oListener)
    OldSheet = oController.ActiveSheet
    HandlingActivationEvent = False
    MsgBox "Now Listening"
End Sub

Sub ActivListener_activeSpreadsheetChanged( oEvent )
    If HandlingActivationEvent Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    HandlingActivationEvent = True
    oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController
    newSheet = oController.ActiveSheet
    oController.setActiveSheet(OldSheet)

    col = oController.getFirstVisibleColumn()
    row = oController.getFirstVisibleRow()
    oController.setActiveSheet(newSheet)
    oController.setFirstVisibleColumn(col)
    oController.setFirstVisibleRow(row)

    'MsgBox col & ", " & row
    OldSheet = newSheet
    HandlingActivationEvent = False
End Sub
```

To make it work, go to `Tools -> Customize`.  In the Events tab, assign `RegisterMyActivationEventListener` to the `Open Document` event.

**Explanation of the code**:

Instead of scrolling the sheets at the same time, it just scrolls to the appropriate cell whenever a different sheet is activated.  It uses the [XViewPane](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XViewPane.html) interface to see where the previous sheet is scrolled, and scrolls the next sheet to that same spot.

To find out when a sheet gets activated, the code uses [an event listener](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Basic/Listeners) for the [XActivationEventListener](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XActivationEventListener.html) interface.

Comment: Thanks, that looks daunting but good! I've never done anything with macros or Basic before, so I've followed a quick tutorial and have made a Hello World macro that seems to work. Where and how do I implement the code you've provided? I tried copying it all into the macro module but that gives a compiler error ""Expected Sub" from the "Dim oListener".

I hope it's not too complicated to explain with my complete inexperience!

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and implemented the code fully.  You should now be able to copy and paste it without any changes.

Comment: I don't know if you'll see this, @Jim, but I was wondering if it'd be easy to also have the same active cell be selected when switching sheets, as part of the same macro. I searched and found a few tutorials about finding which cell was selected, but none saying how to then set the selected cell after finding the row and column.

Comment: Section 6.5.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) tells how to select a cell.