# Can I refer to the location of the active cell in one worksheet, in another worksheet?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Does LibreOffice Calc have a function which returns the active (clicked) row or cell in a worksheet?

I have a large sheet containing rows of data (called "Data") and another worksheet which displays stuff calculated from a specific row of that sheet with relevant statistical aggregations of data from "data" (this sheet is called "Comparators")

At present I have to enter into "Comparators" the number of a row in "Data" to display. It would be so much nicer if one could simply click on a row or a cell in "Data" and then view the "Comparators" sheet for that click-selected row.

(No interest in Excel-specific answers.  It must work in LibreOffice Calc. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any spreadsheet function, but it can be done with macro code.  Have a look at this link:  https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33400.

What I would probably do is set up a listener so that the macro runs whenever the "Comparators" sheet is activated.  An example of such a listener is shown in my answer here: [How to scroll all libreoffice calc spreadsheet sheets together. (Or other ~3D-like ideas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240690/how-to-scroll-all-libreoffice-calc-spreadsheet-sheets-together-or-other-3d-li/35244220#35244220).

Comment: Thanks. A lot to digest here!